# Select a Checkbox in a Table If Row Includes X Value with Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am using Selenium to navigate through a reporting website.

I log in and navigate to a page where I can search for a particular person and then I get a table of information.

Each row has a checkbox which I can click and make an action against that particular record.

I am looking to hit a checkbox in the row of the year equal to the 17-18. But I can't figure out how to make a selection of one element if another element meets a particular value

Comment: Post the website, post your code. People are much more likely to help you, since we can simply copy it, edit it and post the correct result here...

Comment: can you put a html code or screenshot of a table in the question, it would help to answer the question better

Comment: I have added the HTML code I have had to cleanse it of sensitive information. It's a bit messy copies from the source.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the rows that contains text **17-18** and then you can use that element to query the checkbox withing that row

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='academicYearColumnValue' and text()='17-18']/..")
for row in rows: 
    checkbox = row.find_element(".//input[@type='checkbox']")
    checkbox.click()
```

or you can simple query all the checkbox you are interested in using following xpath.

```
all_checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='academicYearColumnValue' and text()='17-18']/../input[@type='checkbox']")
for checkbox in all_checkboxes:
    checkbox.click()
```